# Alternative way to add Apps to LaunchPad

Tags: settings, macbook-pro, launchpad

I noticed that its possible to add custom apps to the launchpad by dragging apps to the launchpad on the dock. However I removed it from dock, but still want to add an application without dragging it all the way to the dock. Is there a right click option or something similar that allows such feature ?

Platform : rMBP Mountain Lion V 10.8

Any suggestions please ? I Do not want to use 3rd party apps.

--

I have yet to find an alternative method, can someone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Launchpad Cleaner](http://launchpadcleaner.com/).  Its a nice app for managing LaunchPad. They have a free and $5.00 version.

Comment: Is there a way without using 3rd party apps ?